# DataTables Responsive Plugin Overflow on small screens

Tags: css, responsive-design, datatables

I'm having an issue with the Responsive plugin for DataTables (version 1.10.4) which can be seen in the provided image. I'm currently trying to get this to display correctly on phones where the screen is small. The issue happens when the columns become small enough that they cannot be shrunk anymore. Instead of Responsive automatically hiding the column it leaves it visible until most of the column overflows before hiding it.

It seems to ignore the containing div width and instead only cares about the window size. It does work correctly for some tables (the widths just happen to line up correctly so Responsive hides all the correct columns)

I don't 'think' this is a custom CSS issue but I may be wrong. Any ideas on a fix or what I could do to troubleshoot this issue?

Updating DataTables to a newer version is possible but not ideal (lots of tables are using retired plugins and would require a lot of modifications)

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you whip out a jsfiddle example showcasing your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my issue. Big thanks to the posts at https://github.com/DataTables/Responsive/issues/20 for pointing me in the right direction.

The version of response I was using was 1.0.2 and the bug appears to have been fixed in 1.0.4.

Ended up upgrading DataTables to the newest version (1.10.4 to 1.10.10) and adding in the newest versions of the two 'retired' plugins TableTools and ColVis which seem to work just fine so I didn't need to do a ton of refactoring.
https://www.datatables.net/download/packages